# Video Call software with redirection / routing

Tags: linux, video-conferencing

Is there a video call software on linux that I can use in the following manner :

User A calls User B. User B has a specific userID / number / Identifier / ... that User A uses.

The software in User B 's side sees the userID / number / Identifier / ... of User A. Then it automatically redirects the call to User C, using User C -s userID / number / Identifier / ...

If User D calls User B, then the call is again redirected to User E.

So, what I am looking for is a rudimentary call redirection (or routing, as mentioned in comment below) functionality.

Is there something like that available?
Thank you.

Comment: IMHO this you search for is named call routing, not redirect

Answer (score 1):

Call routing is doable with a telephony server like [Asterisk](https://www.asterisk.org/) or [FreeSWITCH](https://freeswitch.com/).

You then use a SIP client as the "phone" and call into the Asterisk service which does the call routing.

For setting up Asterisk to handle this, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39232561/route-call-in-asterisk-server